# How can I unload/load pages using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the things I want to achieve with jQuery.

1. First of all, I want to save a copy of the entire page as is in a variable.
2. I then want to replace the currently loaded page with a loading page from another html file or URL without redirecting to that page.
3. After it has done loading, I want to replace the page back with what it originally was (the variable from step 1).

Comment: So, you want to create a [single page app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) - you'll note in that page that under "popular frameworks" for doing this, jquery is not mentioned

Comment: @JaromandaX Not really a app, this is just a one-off thing for letting the user know that the page is loading meanwhile it is loading in the background.

Comment: but the process of a SPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The question asked**

1. At it's simplest (and this is a gross simplification that will lose state like event handlers, iframe state, shadow DOM etc.) you "save a copy" of the page's HTML by using `.html()` on the root element (`html` or `body` for example).
2. You can replace the entire top level element with fixed content from another HTML file or URL by providing the data to the same `.html(data)` function as well.
3. You can restore the original content by repeating step 2 using the data you saved off in step 1.

```
// Step 1 - save old page
const oldPage = $('html').html();

// result of fetch() or fixed HTML from file
// const newHTML = ...

// Step 2 - load new page
$('html').html(newHTML);

// Step 3 - restore old page
$('html').html(oldPage);
```

**What you might actually want**

If you only care that the user can't see the old page, you may want to wrap all of the UI inside a `div` that you can set `display` property to `none` on.  You could also just overlay the new UI elements on top of the old one, possibly wrapped in a container with a solid background (to prevent old UI elements from being shown through transparent background).

Comment: @EmilioPersson sure thing. If your problem is resolved, please upvote/accept answer to indicate such